# Save every array element in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, scroll

```
var boks = ['.menu-469', '.menu-471', '.menu-470'];
var element = ['#about', '#slider', '#afisha'];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $('#main-menu li' + boks[i]).click(function() {
       $(window).scrollTo($(element[i]), 800);
       alert(element[i]);
    });
}
```

This code is always scrolling to the latest array element in my example it's #afisha. How can i make such functionality - when i click on `#main-menu li.menu-469` my page scrolls down to the `#about`, when i click on `#main-menu li.menu-471` it scrolls down to `#slider`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Definitely a dup. Different scenario but same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your for loop has ended the value of `i` has reached your last index, so you need to create an inner self-executing function (a closure) and pass the actual value of `i`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    (function(i) {
       $('#main-menu li' + boks[i]).click(function() {
          $(window).scrollTo($(element[i]), 800);
          alert(element[i]);
       });
    }(i));
}
```